# Any better way to hide multiple elements at once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This works perfectly fine, but for future reference I would like to know if there is a better way to do this.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].style.display = 'none';
document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].style.display = 'none';
document.getElementsByTagName("p")[1].style.display = 'none';
document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.display = 'none';
document.getElementsByTagName("hr")[0].style.display = 'none';
```

I'm open to using jQuery if it would help.

Comment: while you tag a jquery .. you need that with jquery?

Comment: If you didn't mention jquery in your question, should it be better removing `jquery` tag?

Comment: @TaoP.R.: No. It's fine to tag `jquery` even if you're not using it in the question, to indicate that jQuery-specific answers are fine. It better to specifically say that in the text when you're not using jQuery at all in the question, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While jQuery wasn't specifically requested, it would be the shortest implementation to meet the OP's sample code exactly as written:

```
$('h1:eq(0), ul:eq(0), hr:eq(0), p:lt(2)').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep your nodes in an *Array*, then you can write some functions which will hide or show a whole *Array* (or *NodeList*) at once, e.g.

```
function display_none(nodelist) {
    var i = nodelist.length;
    while (i-- > 0)
        nodelist[i].style.display = 'none';
}

function display_default(nodelist) {
    var i = nodelist.length;
    while (i-- > 0)
        nodelist[i].style.display = '';
}
```

So you have

```
var elms = [
    document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0],
    document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0],
    document.getElementsByTagName("p")[1],
    document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0],
    document.getElementsByTagName("hr")[0]
];
```

Now can simply do

```
display_none(elms); // hide them all
display_default(elms); // return to default
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pure Javascript option that implements a jQuery-like extension for the `:lt(n)` pseudo selector so you can specify however many of each tag you want.

As the question asked, this operates on the first two `"p"` tags, then the first `"h1"`, `"ul"` and `"hr"` tags:

```
function hideItems(selector) {
    var r = /:lt\((\d+)\)/;
    selector.split(',').forEach(function(item) {
         var len, elems, i, m = item.match(r);
         if (m) {
             item = item.replace(r, "");
             elems = document.querySelectorAll(item);
             len = Math.min(+m[1], elems.length);
         } else {
             elems = document.querySelectorAll(item);
             len = elems.length;
         }
         for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            elems[i].style.display = 'none';
         }
     });    
}

hideItems('p:lt(2),h1:lt(1),ul:lt(1),hr:lt(1)');
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/m9vspymz/

Answer (score -1):

### [Using Pure JavaScript](http://jsfiddle.net/NuR2Z/45/)

```
//gets all DOM elements with a tag of p or li
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('p,li');
//loops over all elements
for(var i = 0;i < elems.length; i++)
{
    //hides each element in the array
    elems[i].style.display = 'none';   
}
```

---

### Code Specifically for you

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('p,h1,ul,hr');
for(var i = 0;i < elems.length; i++)
{
    elems[i].style.display = 'none';   
}
```

Comment: Only issue is that it hide all of the `p` but I have a 3rd one that need to remain visible.

Comment: @BrandonHellman please update your question with your full HTML and your desired result, thanks

Comment: I think the OP's example is fairly clear; hide the 1st instances of `h1, ul, hr` and the 1st two instances of `p`.

Comment: @tavnab if he has 5 p elements he only wants to hide the first 2? I don't think making that assumption is a good plan.

Comment: @abc123 I agree that this question can be made clearer. Brandon, can you please provide a sample of the actual HTML that's being manipulated?

Comment: @tavnab is correct. There isn't really a specific HTML for me to post, but it more of a general thing that I could use. Like  ('h1, "p[0]", p[1], ul, hr');` but obviously the two p do not work.

Comment: @BrandonHellman for simplicity use jQuery then if you are able.

Comment: @abc123 yep that is what I am going to do, thank you.

Answer (score -2):

## Here's the code (*JavaScript*):

```
var n = [ // 'tagname',which in order
'h1',0,
'p',0,
'p',1,
'ul',0,
'hr',0
];
for(var i = 0;i < elems.length)
{
    document.getElementsByTagName(n[i*2])[(n[i*2]+1)].style.display = 'none';
    i++;
    i++;
}
```

Comment: This one has me confused.  `n` is an array.  So, what is `document.getElementsByTagName(n*2)` supposed to be doing?  Did you mean `document.getElementsByTagName(i*2)`?

Comment: I think you meant `document.getElementsByTagName(i[n*2])`. Also, `i++; i++; ` should be `i += 2;`

Comment: With this approach, you're potentially searching for the same tag name multiple times, when you only need to do this once. Why not store an object with properties keyed by tag name, each of which holds an array of indices (e.g. `var tagIndices = {}; tagIndices['p'] = [0, 1]; ...`), then iterate over the keys? This way you guarantee that any tag name is only dealt with once. I think you also meant `n.length` instead of `elems.length`.

Comment: sorry, a mistake, it's `n[i*2]`